# Clean way to scan for automapper profiles from an assembly

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm trying to get all automapper profiles from an assembly but it seems to get even those that are from automapper since some derive from the Profile Class.

I have a hack that feels dirty. I have to filter profiles that come from automapper since some have no default constructor causing exceptions during resolution e.g the private class NamedProfile that derives from Profile

```
public AutomapperTypeAdapterFactory()
{
    //scan all assemblies finding Automapper Profile
    var profiles = AppDomain.CurrentDomain
                            .GetAssemblies()
                            .SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes())
                            .Where(t => t.BaseType == typeof(Profile));

    Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
    {
        foreach (var item in profiles)
        {
            if (item.FullName != null && !item.FullName.StartsWith("AutoMapper")) // HACK: Removes classes that derive from profile in automapper
                    cfg.AddProfile(Activator.CreateInstance(item) as Profile);
       }
   });
}
```

Is there a cleaner way to go about this?

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Configuration.html#assembly-scanning-for-auto-configuration

Comment: I don't think it's any cleaner since you have got to know the name of the assembly which am trying to avoid for any hard coding @LucianBargaoanu

Comment: There are many overloads, surely you can find the right one.